# MediaRecorder throws exception when setting audio source (android developing)

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder

I am trying to build a simple app to record a voice command and send it to Amazon Alexa, for that purpose I am following this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audio_capture.htm) to record a voice command. The following code snippet causes me trouble:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button play,stop,record;
    private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
    private String outputFile = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    record=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(false);
    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";;

    myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); ***ERROR***
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
```

By throwing the following error stack:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.michael.test, PID: 20504
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.michael.test/com.example.michael.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                              at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.example.michael.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
04-25 12:35:39.109 20504-20504/com.example.michael.test I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20504 SIG: 9
```

All googling points to the issue being the rights not set properly for the app to access the audio source, however my androidmanifest.xml does include the following lines:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

So I am at a loss what else could be going wrong here... I am developing with Android Studio using a LG Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 to test. SDK is set to Android 5.0.

Answer (score 13):

After about three days of research, I decided to check the Application Manager (Settings > Applications > Application Manager > MyRecorderApp > Permissions) while MyRecorderApp was running. As it turned out, there were no "Dangerous permissions" (as Google calls them) for MyRecorderApp, so I turned them on manually first (my app stopped crashing ever since) which led me to find the information below (from Google and [this blog](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal)).

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Quote from Google: [Complete explanation from Google's developers website](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Below is the short version of code that I derived from Google's page and the aforementioned sources. The idea is to ask the user permission to record audio and access the phone's folder the first time they launch the app, that is, after they install it. It worked for my Android M (6.0.1), Android Studio 2.1.1

Add the following declarations

```
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
private boolean permissionToWriteAccepted = false;
private String [] permissions = {"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
```

Add the following Override code block. You can also add it with an Android Studio template by pressing "Alt" + "Insert" (Windows) or "control" + "O" (Mac), then look for the onRequestPermissionsResult option which will be down the list.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case 200:
            permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            permissionToWriteAccepted  = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
            break;
    }
    if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) MainActivity.super.finish();
    if (!permissionToWriteAccepted ) MainActivity.super.finish();

}
```

Finally, add this " if " statement to your onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Add the following code to your onCreate
    int requestCode = 200;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Solved a big problem of mine. Would upvote a few times if it were possible.